# Move Window to second Screen

Tags: windows-10, pyautogui, python-3.9

I want to move the currently active window to a different monitor (left or right) with Python.
The shortcut on Windows for this is usually WIN + shift + arrow key [left|right]. I tried it with a bunch of libraries, but none of them do the trick somehow.

I tried pyautogui:

```py
pyautogui.hotkeys('shift', 'win', 'left')
```

The longer solution doesn't work either

```py
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.keyDown('win')
pyautogui.press('left')
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
pyautogui.keyUp('win')
```

Neither does any combination of different buttons like as "winleft" or "shiftright" and such.
Changing the order of the shift and win key does also nothing more for me.
All it does is move the window to the edge of the screen (similar to WIN + left).

Then I started testing other libraries, such as pynput:

```py
hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
    keyboard.HotKey.parse('<shift>+<cmd>+<left>'),
    None
)
```

This one seems to be for monitoring purposes, tho.

After that, I discovered win32gui (and win32api). This one has next to no documentation that is actually helpful for anything (imho).

Does anyone know why pyautogui does not properly execute this specific shortcut and how to make it do it? Or does anyone know how to execute that shortcut in a different way?

Comment: win is also called meta key.
Try pyautogui.hotkeys('shift', ‘meta', 'left')

Comment: 1) No it's not https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys
2) It registers the "win" key, it just executes the wrong shortcut

Answer (score 0):

It seems like pyautogui doesn't support this functionality for some reason. I managed to move the window with pynput, though, like this:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

keyboard.press(Key.cmd)
keyboard.press(Key.shift)
keyboard.press(Key.left)
keyboard.release(Key.cmd)
keyboard.release(Key.shift)
keyboard.release(Key.left)
```